# Efficient Generation of Random Variates from a Copula Distribution

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

I have a 7-asset portfolio for which I want to simulate daily log-deltas using a Student T copula.  The marginal distributions are all either Stable or TsallisQGaussian.  Using **NMaximize**, I have already determined that the copula *dof* = 9.

The asset correlation matrix, *corrmat*, is:

```
corrmat = {{1., 0.491789, 0.382652, -0.580449, 0.34607, -0.0887926, 
  0.292343}, {0.491789, 1., 0.475475, -0.713583, 0.364887, -0.112926, 
  0.372419}, {0.382652, 0.475475, 1., -0.695327, 0.370684, -0.0894264,
   0.359768}, {-0.580449, -0.713583, -0.695327, 1., -0.498612, 
  0.1529, -0.482753}, {0.34607, 0.364887, 0.370684, -0.498612, 
  1., -0.0433323, 0.291971}, {-0.0887926, -0.112926, -0.0894264, 
  0.1529, -0.0433323, 1., -0.0954981}, {0.292343, 0.372419, 
  0.359768, -0.482753, 0.291971, -0.0954981, 1.}}
```

from which the conditioned VCV matrix, *vcvmat*, is:

```
vcvmat = {{0.9586172917, -0.03410852909, -0.2933963066, 0.1208800096, 
  0.1706880212, 0.1239885803, -0.06784705084}, {-0.03410852909, 
  0.6979797397, 
  0.02009209742, -0.001634295474, -0.02837172149, -0.02564790389, 
  0.01303223508}, {-0.2933963066, 0.02009209742, 
  0.7314875880, -0.1494059087, -0.3716208429, -0.2204546813, 
  0.1000107891}, {0.1208800096, -0.001634295474, -0.1494059087, 
  0.8597301696, 0.1366021203, 
  0.07930474269, -0.05334637064}, {0.1706880212, -0.02837172149, \
-0.3716208429, 0.1366021203, 1.136447366, 
  0.2592871862, -0.06289877472}, {0.1239885803, -0.02564790389, \
-0.2204546813, 0.07930474269, 0.2592871862, 
  1.154068011, -0.02358813328}, {-0.06784705084, 0.01303223508, 
  0.1000107891, -0.05334637064, -0.06289877472, -0.02358813328, 
  0.8678362987}}
```

The respective marginal distributions are:

```
mda = StableDistribution[1, 1.66576, -0.205451, -0.00149914, 0.00932388]
mdb = TsallisQGaussianDistribution[0.000198498, 0.0124003, 1.43148]
mdc = StableDistribution[1, 1.84146, -0.453362, 0.000669985, 0.00802551]
mdd = TsallisQGaussianDistribution[-0.00129644,0.0112156, 1.52237]
mde = TsallisQGaussianDistribution[0.000625683, 0.0147539, 1.46668]
mdf = StableDistribution[1, 1.45877, 0.253482, 0.000708238, 0.00111962]
mdg = TsallisQGaussianDistribution[0.00064191, 0.0121773, 1.52216]
```

Given these values, the entire copula expression is:

```
tCopula = CopulaDistribution[{"MultivariateT", vcvmat, 9}, 
              {mda, mdb, mdc, mdd, mde, mdf, mdg}];
```

So far, so good.

The problem is the requisite calculation time.  Here are the outputs:

```
In: Timing[x = RandomVariate[tCopula, 100];]
Out: {8.917131, Null}

In: Timing[y = RandomVariate[tCopula, 1000];]
Out: {92.197472, Null}

In: Timing[z = RandomVariate[tCopula, 10000];]
Out: {921.512002, Null}
```

The computation times are roughly linear, and since 10,000 samples is a bare minimum for meaningful analysis, simulating a mere 7-asset portfolio is at least a fifteen minute proposition.

Is there a way to call this simulation more efficiently within *Mathematica* 9?  FWIW, I'm using *Mathematica* on a Mac, so Finance Platform isn't an option.

---

Sasha,

Thanks for taking the time to unbundle all that functionality.

For the benefit of anyone else who wants to run the simulation, be aware that Mma threw a non-Hermitian error when I evaluated the *data* argument the way Sasha initially set it up.  I went back and adjusted the machine precision of my VCV matrix, and I created a separate variable, *v2mat*, for Sasha's expression

```
vcvmat/KronekerProduct[Sqrt[Diagonal[vcvmat]],Sqrt[Diagonal[vcvmat]]]
```

Then I evaluated

```
RandomVariate[MultivariateTDistribution[v2mat, dof], 10^4]
```

and it worked fine. For purposes of comparison, I reran the original tCopula argument for a 10^4 x 7 set of observations:

```
In: Timing[data1 = RandomVariate[tCopula, 10000];]
Out: {888.577837, Null}
```

versus a 10^4 x 7 set of values from Sasha's method:

```
In: Timing[data2 = Transpose[MapThread[#1[#2]&, {qfs, Transpose[data]}]];]
Out: {4.322776, Null}
```

Quite a difference.

Here's a graphical juxtaposition after running the same Mahalanobis distance multivariate outlier routine on both data sets.

[image: data1]

[image: data2]

Not only is Sasha's method much faster, if anything it appears to yield more representative random variates.

Comment: Unfortunately `CopulaDistribution` cannot be compiled (see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/which-distributions-can-be-compiled-using-randomvariate). Maybe you would have more luck using RLink? http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/copula/html/Copula.html http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/index.html I'm not sure how efficient the R implementation is, though it seems to be written in C.

Answer (score 20):

A nice question.

Sampling from `tCopula` is done in stages. First a sample is generated from the copula with uniform marginal distributions, and then quantiles of appropriate marginal distributions are applied to the respective slots.

Most of the time goes into evaluation of these quantiles, and they are expensive to compute. Being interested in $\geqslant 10^4$ sample points, the performance can be enhanced by interpolating quantile functions of marginals using [monotonic interpolation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5929/ow-to-create-an-interpolated-cdf-from-its-samples/11859#11859):

```
FritschCarlsonInterpolation[data_] := 
 Module[{del, slopes, tau}, del = #2/#1 & @@@ Differences[data];
  slopes = Flatten[{del[[1]], MovingAverage[del, 2], del[[-1]]}];
  tau = MapThread[Min, Through[{Append, Prepend}[
      Min[#, 1] & /@ (3 del/(Norm /@ Partition[slopes, 2, 1])), 1]]];
  Interpolation[ Transpose[{List /@ data[[All, 1]], data[[All, -1]], slopes tau}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, Method -> "Hermite"]]
```

Let's build interpolants in the bulk of the quantile space.

```
qgrid = With[{n = 100}, 
   Join[{0.001, 0.002, 0.005, 0.007}, 
    Range[1./n, (n - 1.)/n, 1./n], {0.993, 0.995, 0.998, 0.999}]];

AbsoluteTiming[
 interpolants = 
   Table[FritschCarlsonInterpolation[
     Table[{q, Quantile[di, q]}, {q, qgrid}]], {di, {mda, mdb, mdc, 
      mdd, mde, mdf, mdg}}];]

(* {20.770029, Null} *)
```

Now build quantile functions by using interpolants in the bulk, and the original `Quantile[dist,q]` for tails:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 qfs = MapThread[
    Function[{di, qf}, 
     Function @@ {q, 
       Piecewise[{{qf[q], Min[qgrid] <= q <= Max[qgrid]}}, Quantile[di, q]], 
       Listable}], {{mda, mdb, mdc, mdd, mde, mdf, mdg}, 
     interpolants}];]

(* {0.010000, Null} *)
```

Unfortunately it seems one can beat multivariate T `CopulaDistribution` at random number generation:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 data = RandomVariate[
   MultivariateTDistribution[
    vcvmat/KroneckerProduct[Sqrt[Diagonal[vcvmat]], 
      Sqrt[Diagonal[vcvmat]]], dof], 10^5];
 data = ArrayReshape[CDF[StudentTDistribution[dof], Flatten[data]], 
   Dimensions[data]];]

(* {0.250000, Null} *)
```

The variable `data` now contains $10^5$ sample data points from the multivariate-T copula with 9 degrees of freedom and correlation structure determined by `vcvmat` and uniform marginals.

It now remains to apply the constructed quantile functions to these sample vectors:

```
In[49]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 data = Transpose[MapThread[#1[#2] &, {qfs, Transpose[data]}]];]

Out[49]= {62.410087, Null}
```

Thus we got around to generate $10^5$ 7-tuples in under 2 minutes of the total time. You can adjust the interpolation grid to improve the accuracy as needed.

Comment: This is absolutely great,

Answer (score 9):

With the help of comments on this and other stackexchange pages I managed to solve the problem of how to use custom distributions in things like `CopulaDistribution` (and other functions like `RandomVariate`, `Expectation`, etc), and given that it took me a couple of days’ hard slog I thought I’d share my discoveries with this community. Please excuse the flippant nature of the following – it started life as an email to a friend and colleague of mine… :)

(Also, please note that `Random```DistributionVector`, mentioned by Sasha in one of the linked posts above, appears to have been changed to `Random```Private```DistributionVector` in the production release of v9.0.1)

I needed a *Mathematica* version of Tukey’s “g-and-h” distribution, which is a transform of Z ~ N[0,1] ...

```
Xgh = A + B/g(Exp[g*Z] - 1)Exp[(h*Z^2)/2]
```

OK, you’d think just use

```
ghd = TransformedDistribution[Xgh, Distributed[Z, NormalDistribution[0,1]]
```

would you not?

Turns out that, even though the above is valid, it takes a very (VERY) long time to compute `CDF[ghd, X]`, or even `Quantile[ghd, p]`. I tried a number of tricks including `Compile`, taking a Taylor series, etc, but I’ve concluded (reluctantly) it’s not viable to use `TransformedDistribution` for g-and-h.

OK then, you’d think just use the g-and-h cdf prob in

```
ghd = ProbabilityDistribution[{“CDF”, prob}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

would you not?

Turns out that a symbolic form of the pdf and/or cdf is problematic, and using

```
prob = CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (Z /. FindRoot[Xgh == x, {Z,0}])]
```

doesn’t cut it with *Mathematica*. It wants something symbolic inside `ProbabilityDistribution`.

So, I reverted back to my “hand-rolled” (custom) distribution that I’d written before the new fancy enhanced `Distributions` came out in v8 & v9. It already had all the std *Mathematica* things like CDF (implemented as the `FindRoot` of Xgh), `PDF`, `InverseCDF`, `Random`, `Quantile`, `Mean`, `Variance`, etc, via the `TagSet` feature (ie, defining “up values” of the distribution name). Eg...

```
GandHDistribution/: InverseCDF[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_], fraction_] :=
  Xgh[A, B, g, h, Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], fraction]] /; 
    DistributionParameterQ[GandHDistribution[A, B, g, h]]
```

But it turns out that there are a lot of undocumented test functions used by `CopulaDistribution` that you also need to define. Also, some of the pre-v8 internals had changed, e.g., `ParameterQ` is now `DistributionParameterQ`. I found out what was needed by `Unprotect[CopulaDistribution]` and then removing the `ReadProtected` attribute so that I can see all the required up-value definitions. They appear to be (aside from the “well-known” things like `InverseCDF` and `DistributionParameterQ` mentioned above)...

```
GandHDistribution/: DistributionParameterQ[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_]] := And[
    If[FreeQ[N[A], Complex], True,
       Message[GandHDistribution::realparm, A]; False],
    If[FreeQ[N[B], Complex], True,
       Message[GandHDistribution::realparm, B]; False],
    If[FreeQ[N[g], Complex], True,
       Message[GandHDistribution::realparm, g]; False],
    If[FreeQ[N[h], Complex], True,
       Message[GandHDistribution::realparm, h]; False]
];

GandHDistribution::posparm =
  "Parameter `1` is expected to be positive."

GandHDistribution::realparm = "Parameter `1` is expected to be real."

GandHDistribution/: 
  DistributionParameterAssumptions[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_]]:=
Element[{A,B,g,h},Reals]   

GandHDistribution/: 
  RandomVariate[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_], dim_] :=
    Module[
      {dimv=Flatten[{dim}] (*if dim is single int, convert to single element list*)},
      Map[Xgh[A, B, g, h, #]&, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],dimv], {Length@dimv}]
    ] /; (IntegerQ[dim] && dim > 0) || VectorQ[dim, (IntegerQ[#] && # > 0)&];

GandHDistribution/: 
  Random`Private`
    DistributionVector[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_],
                       n_Integer, prec_?Positive] :=
      Xgh[A, B, g, h, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n, 
        WorkingPrecision -> prec]];

GandHDistribution/: 
 Statistics`CopulaDistributionDump` 
   UnivariateDistributionListQ[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_]] := True;

GandHDistribution/: 
  Statistics`Library`
    ContinuousUnivariateDistributionQ[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_]] := True;

GandHDistribution/: 
  Statistics`Library`
    DiscreteUnivariateDistributionQ[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_]] := False;

GandHDistribution/: 
  Statistics`Library`
    ContinuousMultivariateDistributionQ[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_]] := False;

GandHDistribution/: 
  Statistics`Library`
    DiscreteMultivariateDistributionQ[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_]] := False;

GandHDistribution/: 
  Statistics`Library`
    DistributionNParameterQ[GandHDistribution[A_, B_, g_, h_]]:=
     DistributionParameterQ[GandHDistribution[A, B, g, h]];
```

Now it works like a dream – the `CopulaDistribution` function is fantastic.

Comment: Could you try to format a little bit better your answer? The topic is very interesting and it would be nice to have your answer properly formatted for future readers...

Comment: Interesting, why arent DistributionDomain and DistributionParameterAssumptions not defined in your example ?

Comment: added RandomVariate (which I didn't initially realise was not automatically derived from DistributionVector). Filled in the DistributionDomain and DistributionParameterAssumptions defns while I was at it.

Comment: @doug fromoz: I wonder if it would be possible to add  those other functions
such as 'PDF', 'CDF'  to your answer. Thanks.