# Optimization of custom probability distibutions?

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, random, distributions, timing

Consider the two tests:

```
Timing[Do[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 0.3]], {200}]]
```

> {0.001188, Null}

```
MyNormalDistribution[mu_,sig_] = ProbabilityDistribution[1/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]sig)
             Exp[-(x - mu)^2/(2 sig^2))], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}];
Timing[Do[RandomVariate[MyNormalDistribution[0.5, 0.3]], {200}]]
```

> {3.375444, Null}

So it seems that the built in normal distribution is much faster (~3000 times faster!) then the custom one. My question is how is this optimization done and whether it can be implemented for custom distributions as well?

Comment: Related questions: [(1124)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/which-distributions-can-be-compiled-using-randomvariate), [(20067)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20067/efficient-generation-of-random-variates-from-a-copula-distribution?lq=1), [(56180)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56180/speed-up-adding-poisson-noise-to-an-image?lq=1), [(75303)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75303/can-mathematicas-random-number-generation-be-improved?lq=1)

Comment: In particular question #1124

Comment: The LHS of your definition should read `MyNormalDistribution[mu_, sig_]` Without the patterns, `MyNormalDistribution[0.5, 0.3]` is undefined. Even after this correction, `RandomVariate[MyNormalDistribution[0.5, 0.3]]` does not return a value. `RandomVariate` only works with the built-in distributions. You would need to define an upvalue for `MyNormalDistribution` to have `RandomVariate` work.

Comment: @BobHanlon, You are right about the missing underscores, thanks. This was a typo. However, RandomVariate does work with custom distributions (at least in v10). Feel free to try it yourself....

Comment: @JeffDror - You are correct. I though I had tried `RandomVariate` with the custom distribution but in a new session it worked fine.

Comment: Do you really require them one at a time? Is the distribution changing between calls (only real reason I can think of that would need singlets)? Otherwise, produce them in bulk, will be orders of magnitude faster.